# Python 3: Explanations of the results from cProfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, profiling, cprofile

I am currently trying to improve the speed of my python 3 code is and I ran a cProfile on my code to see what takes up the most time. The problem is that I don't understand what those methods represent from the output.

I attached below the output from the console ordered by the most time that it took. I tried googling the said methods but did not find anything useful. If someone knows what they mean or if there is a specific website that has a dictionary of what those are it would be perfect. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: `__init__`, `__enter__`, `__exit__` are about initialising classes and contexts. The crucial information is in the `filename` column. 
If you're using pandas you're probably using some sort of machine learning thing. In which case, 10 minutes might not be so bad. I would focus on improving obvious things in the code you've written, rather than cProfile.

Comment: @blueteeth Thank you for explaining that! I am indeed using pandas to calculate some metrics. If I were to understand it correctly, the  `__init__`, `__enter__`, `__exit__` are used when specific methods from a class inside a library are called?

Comment: Yes, I would guess so.